# how can I find the minumm of items which is less than a number from list of lists with heap?

Tags: python, list, heap

I had a question in my exam today.
Consider I have a list like this:

```
[[0, 0], [95, 1], [0, 5], [200, 3], [1000, 4], [300, 2]]
```

how can I find elements which their ele[0] values are less than a certain value and ele[1] is the minimum among them all?
example: if input `n=100?`
then `[0, 0], [95, 1], [0, 5]` have less `ele[0]` value than `100`, and `[0,0]` is the minimum.
so the output should be `[0,0]`
The question wanted us to do it with a heap but I don't know how. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by finding a [simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) - which program *can* you write which comes closest to what you need? Can you solve it without using a heap? Can you use a heap to find the minimum of a list of numbers, without pairs of numbers and the added condition?

Comment: Can you clarify whether there will be more than one query on the same input list? You spoke of "remove elements", and in plural. What is the expected output? Is it the shortened list? Can you give a complete example of input and expected output, with multiple queries if possible?

Comment: I can do it without heaps. and I can find the minimum of a list of numbers with a heap but I have a problem combining them to solve a bigger problem.

Comment: @trincot I edited the question. also, the output should be one element from the list.

Comment: If you just need to do this once on a list, there is no benefit in creating another data structure for it: you would just scan the input once and you would know the result at the end. I presume there is something missing here, that's why I asked about "multiple queries"... If it really is a case where your input consists of the list and of `n`, and no multiple queries, then there is no need for a heap or any other data structure. That would just make your solution slower.

Comment: you can use a min-heap data structure to efficiently find the element with the minimum value of ele[1] among the elements with ele[0] values less than a certain value.

Comment: @ezio that's exactly my question. how do you do it? like how do you check that ele[0] is less than a certain value and ele[1] is the minimum at the same time?

Comment: Only add the relevant items to the heap?

Comment: @trincot well I know it's not the most efficient way. but It was in my exam and I'm just struggling to understand how it works with a heap.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this represents an exam question. There must be something missing here, or it is a poor exam question. Please quote the exam question literally.

Comment: @mkrieger1 then you can't do it at the same time. you need two loops one for adding the relevant ones to the heap and another for finding the minimum of them

Comment: What's the problem with that? An alternative would be to add all items to the heap and ignore the ones which don't satisfy the condition when pulling them out.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It's okay but I just wanted to see if there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
from heapq import heappush as push, heappop as pop

def find_min_ele(lst, n):
    h = []
    for a, b in lst:
        if a < n:
            push(h, [b, a])  # reverse!
    return pop(h)[::-1]  # reverse again


>>> find_min_ele([[95, 1], [0, 5], [200, 3], [1000, 4], [300, 2]], 200)
[95, 1]
```